# calculate ratio of matches among texts with quanteda

Tags: r, nlp, similarity, quanteda

To study text reuse in legislative process, I'm trying to assess the similarity among different versions of draft bills. I started using Jaccard's method (intersection over union) for its simplicity, but as it changes the denominator of the division with each combination, it's inconvenient to compare the ratio of reuse between different elements of the law in question, from the point of view of how much text they have preserved from their original versions.

Then I found the **ratio of matches** method, which instead of dividing the intersection among the union, does it over only one of the sets (in this case, texts), but I have no idea how to run it correctly on *quanteda*, that's the tool with which I have been working this corpora. What I tried was to use the `tokens_keep` function to trim the corpus in use to only the tokens present on the reference text, but when trying it on a small example, I got a wildly different result than the one provided by the `ratio_of_matches` function from the *textreuse* package (which I'm not managing to make work in general).

[This is the code example from *textreuse*](https://rdrr.io/cran/textreuse/f/vignettes/textreuse-introduction.Rmd), and it's respective outputs:

```
a <- tokenize_words(paste("How does it feel, how does it feel?",
                          "To be without a home",
                          "Like a complete unknown, like a rolling stone"))
b <- tokenize_words(paste("How does it feel, how does it feel?",
                          "To be on your own, with no direction home",
                          "A complete unknown, like a rolling stone"))

jaccard_similarity(a, b)
jaccard_dissimilarity(a, b)
jaccard_bag_similarity(a, b)
ratio_of_matches(a, b)

[1] 0.65
[1] 0.35
[1] 0.4
[1] 0.75
```

And this is my attempt at replication with *quanteda*:

```
a <- (paste("How does it feel, how does it feel?",
            "To be without a home",
            "Like a complete unknown, like a rolling stone"))
b <- (paste("How does it feel, how does it feel?",
            "To be on your own, with no direction home",
            "A complete unknown, like a rolling stone"))

tibble(texto = c(a, b),
       id = c("a", "b")) -> objeto

b %>% 
  corpus() %>% 
  tokens(remove_punct = T) %>%
  tokens_ngrams(n = 1) %>% 
  tokens_tolower() %>% 
  types() -> b2 #this creates a vector of tokens from b, to keep
                #changed *as.character* with *types*, per Watanabe

objeto %>% 
  corpus(text_field = "texto", docid_field = "id") %>% 
  tokens(remove_punct = T) %>%
  tokens_ngrams(n = 1) %>% 
  tokens_tolower() %>% 
  tokens_keep(b2, valuetype = "fixed") %>% #this should keep only the tokens from b
  dfm() %>%
  textstat_simil(margin = "documents", method = "jaccard") %>% 
  as.matrix()

          a         b
a 1.0000000 0.6842105
b 0.6842105 1.0000000
```

If I run the same *quanteda* script without the `tokens_keep` line, I get the same result from `jaccard_similarity` by *textreuse*, so it's specifically this extra step the one on which I'm introducing an error.

I'll be really thankful of any insight you might give!

Comment: In order to get all the token unique types, you should use `types()` instead of `as.character()`. The use of `tokens_keep()` makes sense to me.

Comment: You are right! But I tried it again with the same example posted and the result is the same, a similarity of 0,6842105 instead of the 0,75 given by ratio_of_matches. What other thing might be going wrong?

Comment: If you are trying to replicate https://github.com/ropensci/textreuse/blob/0f453d603816fcd8521303dee8ac42b35537b5b9/R/similarity.R#L128-L131 using textstats, it might be better to use 'simple matching'. You can also use 'kullback' as an asymmetric measure of divergence.